# Number of complete traversals of the circle in generalised Josephus problem?

Tags: dynamic-programming, linked-lists

In the [generalised Josephus problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem#The_general_case), n people stand in a circle and every kth person is eliminated until only one person is left. The last person left standing can be found using dynamic programming (like [here](https://cp-algorithms.com/others/josephus_problem.html)).

I want to find out the number of times the circle will be traversed completely (ie the number of times the you will have to go through the entire array).

Note that k can be larger than the size of the circle (if not at the starting, at least after the circle  is sufficiently reduced); in the circle maybe traversed completely before the next elimination.

Comment: Calculate a few values and feed them to the OEIS.

Comment: Can you give a few sample values, together with a worked out example? Details could matter here.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/47802/5038, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/131765/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).